# How can I rebind shortcut for mysql client? -- or: How to replace editline with readline for mysql client?

Tags: bash, keyboard-shortcuts, mysql, readline, mariadb

I am using the msyql-client, and I open a mysql prompt on a terminal via:

```
$ mysql -h localhost -uuser -ppassword
mysql>
```

I use the msql client version:

```
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

For terminals with emacs-like bindings, I have a very strong muscle memory to use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>

to delete the last word. Yet inside the mysql client, it deletes back to the start of the line and hence it's hard for me to write or adapt queries.

Can I rebind the keyboard shortcuts for mysql client and, if so, how? I know that I can use Alt + Backspace instead, yet I want to keep my usage consistent.

Comment: `Ctrl-w` is a `readline` function, it should work the same in all `readline`-enabled applications.  If it doesn't work in `mysql` then your `mysql` might be compiled without it.  You can check with `mysql --version` (it should say something like "... using readline 5.1").

Comment: @SatoKatsura I see `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`; I guess "EditLine" is not the same as "ReadLine"?

Comment: Nope.  Complain to the maintainer.

Comment: @SatoKatsura Is readline a de-facto standard? [editline](https://github.com/troglobit/editline) is marketed as a readline alternative without ncurse, so the maintainer might have thought of it as a feature.

Comment: Well, it isn't `readline`, thus the difference with `Ctrl-w`.  No idea if / how it can be configured to do what you want. _shrug_

Comment: @SatoKatsura Understood. If you like you can point this out as an intermediate answer for me to upvote and accept.

Comment: Apparently you can configure `editline(3)` bindings in a file `~/.editrc`.  What you can write there is described in the `tcsh(1)` manual.  You probably want `bind ^W backward-delete-word` (not tested).

Comment: See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/461916/48577) for an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, I installed `mariadb`, the community-driven fork of mysql,  and use its mysql client, since that client comes with readline:

```
sudo apt install mariadb-client
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.29-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

You can use just the same as the mysql client.

---

Keep in mind that it will uninstall mysql, even though I consider this a feature.

It appears the maintainers of mysql dropped readline in favor of editline due to licensing reasons. (Editline seems to be BSD, readline is GNU, and the latter seems to conflict with their desire for providing a commercial version.)

These are the relevant bug reports I found in that regard:

- [MySQL-5.5 readline (editline) -- CTRL-R does not work](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60465)
- [MySQL client is broken without readline](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69991)

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of the `mysql` client, on some platforms/distributions, are built against `editline` rather than `readline` for software licensing reasons.

`editline`'s default binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> often is to delete the entire line up to the cursor position. The way to change that binding to instead delete only the preceding word is to create a file named `.editrc` in your home directory with the following contents:

```
bind "^W" ed-delete-prev-word
```

The `mysql` client will pick up on this the next time you start it.

([source](http://www.arbaouimehdi.com/use-ctrl-w-to-delete-a-word-with-mysql-cli/))